# How to keep JSON spacing while using JSON dump? - Python

Tags: python, json, formatting, pretty-print

I have some very simplified and simulated json that looks like this (Don't comment on the JSON, this is not a real set of key/value pairs):

```
{
    "NAME": "Billy",

    "DETAILS" [{
        "COLOR": "RED",
        "NUMBERS": [
            7,
            12
        ]
    },
    {
        "COLOR": "BLUE",
        "NUMBERS": [
            8,
            113
        ]
    }]
}
```

And then in my python code I have this to read/write to the file (The file path gets found earlier on via pathlib)

```
def editJSON(file, number):
    with file.open() as f:
        data = json.load(f)
        details = data['DETAILS']
        for user in details:
            paths = user['NUMBERS']
            paths.append(number)

    with file.open('w') as outfile:
        json.dump(data, outfile, indent=4)
        print("Added to file: ", file)
```

Why does then my JSON return it formatted incorrectly and how can I keep the spacing I originally had? As you can see `Name` and `Details` get smushed together. Which is fine in this simplified example but with many more k/v pairs it gets very messy to read if the grouping no longer exists. Ideally I just want to be editing the lines of json that have to do with `NUMBERS`

```
{
    "NAME": "Billy",
    "DETAILS" [{
        "COLOR": "RED",
        "NUMBERS": [
            7,
            12,
            14
        ]
    },
    {
        "COLOR": "BLUE",
        "NUMBERS": [
            8,
            113,
            14
        ]
    }]
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately json has its own rules about formatting. I don’t think there is a way to enforce arbitrary rules.

Answer (score 0):

You can use editorconfig ([official site](https://editorconfig.org/)) to format as you want your JSON file and all other files, on save.
After config it will be automatically format.

it’s not a code solution but i think that it can help !

Comment: Which plugin do you think the OP will require?

Comment: editorconfig vscode plugin